# How to hide a file using macro VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose we have a file in a directory of Windows. It doesn't matter if this file was already in Windows or was created by our code. Also, assume that no special permission is required to access this file (such as admin permission).
How and using what statements can we hide this file using macro code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file attribute through FileSystemObject

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dim f
set f = fso.GetFile("C:\... file path...")

f.Attributes = f.Attributes or 2 
' 2 = Hidden, "or" combines it with any existing flags
```

More on the [Attributes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/attributes-property)

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `SetAttr` in VBA that you can use to set file attributes (see [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/setattr-statement)

```
Const Filename = "C:\Users\funThomas\test.txt"
SetAttr Filename, vbHidden
```

This is a wrapper to the good old DOS-command `Attrib` and does exactly the same.

Note that setting the `hidden` flag hides the file only if the user doesn't set the *Show hidden files and folder* option in the Explorer. And this will not work on a Mac.